# Airflow returns list index out of range

Tags: airflow

When I run a clear on all Downstream-Recursive-Failed-Future tasks in `Airflow 1.10.10`

it returns a list index out of range error.

Attached [image: Screenshot]

**DAG definition**

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'I',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 6, 1),
    'email': ['dxxx@yy.com '],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'on_failure_callback': slack_alert
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='aaa',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='my_desc',
        schedule_interval='0 * * * *'
        # schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
```

I do not know if it's a normal issue in Airflow, but before upgrading to `Airflow 2.0` I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: Can you please post traceback as code rather than image? also please post your DAG definition. The error suggest issue with timezone

Comment: @Elad, just added the dag definition and params. I dont have the traceback in code right now.